# reformat array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [A] => khaja.ghc@cdc.com 
        ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [A] => bag@example.com 
        ) 
    )
```

Is there any easy process to store `khaja.ghc@cdc.com` and `bag@example.com` in an array in php? If so please help me.
I am doing this by `foreach()` method and after getting element I stored them in an array. Then finally by `array_push()` method I got the required array. But I think I missed easy process. Can you help me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still can use `foreach` modifing the value. Try

```
foreach($array as $key => &$value) {
    if(is_array($value) && isset($value['A'])) $value = $value['A'];
}
```

and your `$array` will look like you want it to look.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your question:

```
$data = array(array('A' => 'khaja.ghc@cdc.com'), array('A' => 'bag@example.com'));
$result = array();

foreach($data as $element)
  if (is_array($element) && isset($element['A']))
    $result[] = $element['A'];

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save a couple lines of code you can use [array_map](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [create_function](http://pt1.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php):

```
$a = array(array('A' => 'khaja.ghc@cdc.com'), array('A' => 'bag@example.com'));

$result = array_map(create_function('$x','$y = array_values($x); return $y[0];'), $a))
```

Although the saving on the number of code lines, I don't encourage you to take this approach. The code will be much easier to read and understand with a simple `foreach` loop.